# postgres how to choose what to index, what matters, what will make a difference?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a postgres table with ~90M rows.  It has the following columns all type text except as noted:

```
action_id (text - 25 character)
exchangeid (text - 25 character)
flow (text - 25 character)
amt (int 8)
source_rowid (text - 25 character)
dest_rowid (text - 25 character)
hierarchy_level (int8)
date (timestamp)
source (text - 5 character)
destination (text - 5 character)
```

I recently ran a query to count the distinct values in the 'action_id' column:

```
SELECT count( distinct action_id) FROM myTable  (should return 90)
```

When that query failed to complete after 1/2 hour, I decided to index the column and rerun the query which then took 27 minutes.  This surprised me as I expected a query on an indexed column to be much faster than that given it's only 90M rows.

My questions are:

- does indexing improve query speed or just *efficiency*?
- what should I index and why?
- if I index one column does that help in a query that puts conditions on multiple columns that column might be paired with eg. 'WHERE colA = x AND colB = y' where colA is indexed and colB is not; is the query faster if just one column is indexed?

Note that everything I have found so far from googling the topic shows me *how* to index or tells me I *should* with a vague promise of 'faster'.

Update:  Running query with 'explain analyze buffers' gives

[image]

Update 2:  running VACUUM reduced the query time to 11 min.

Update 3:  the index created for the action_id column was simply:
`CREATE INDEX expanded_flows_eng_id ON public.expanded_flows USING btree (action_id)`.  It is 711M, text_ops.  It never seems to get used.

Comment: 30 minutes is astonishing, with an index or without.  I think your computer must be powered by a hamster, which has expired.  First step should be gather some data, by turning on track_io_timing and running the query with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`

Comment: lol it's a macbook 6 core with 32GB RAM.  db is in a docker container but that shouldn't make a difference

Comment: Seq scan indicates it's not using the index. It's possible the statistics the query planner relies on are out of date. Try `vacuum analyze expanded_flows`. See https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/optimize-and-improve-postgresql-performance-with-vacuum-analyze-and-reindex-885239781.html

Comment: yeah sorry about that. fixed typo

Comment: You have 100M rows, not just 9 - but 27 minutes is still way too long for that. The high number of temp buffers written indicates that the grouping can't be done in memory. It looks like IO is quite slow. Can you se `track_io_timing` to `on` (as the superuser) then run `explain (analyze, buffers,  timing)` then we could see how fast the disk is. You could also try increasing `work_mem` substantially but I doubt you can raise it to a level where no temp buffers are written to disk (oh, and btw: the execution plan is better show as formatted text, not as a screen shot)

Comment: `width=25`. What type is action_id?

Comment: action_id is text, alphanumeric string.  vacuum is taking a very long time.

Comment: @MikeB2019x A text ID will slow things down considerably. Perhaps you should tell us about your schema. If there's only a limited set an enum might be applicable.

Comment: It is much less astonishing with 100M rows rather than 9M.  But still, your seq scan seems to proceed at about 19MB/s, which seems quite slow.

Comment: Your query should be able to use an index-only scan on an index on action_id.  That it doesn't do so could be because the table is poorly vacuumed, and so it would need to do a lot of heap fetches.  You could run a manual VACUUM to see if that changes things.  If it does not, you could `set enable_sort=off;` and do an `EXPLAIN` (no need for the ANALYZE) to see if that changes the plan to make it want to use the index.  If it still doesn't, then there must be something wrong with the index or its definition, please show it to us.

Comment: I ran VACUUM and that brought the time down to 11 minutes but the laptop has an SSD so that still seems a lot.  I'm still reading in to how to change the settings ('track_io_timing',' enable_sort') b/c the db is in a docker image.

Comment: @MikeB2019x Just VACUUM? You need to ANALYZE as well.

Comment: @schwern: yup I did vaccum analyze.  I all tried jjanes advice and tried turning enable_sort and track_io on and off.  At no point does it look like the index is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> action_id is text, alphanumeric string

Your query is already pretty slow with an integer, about 35 seconds. Text will slow things down considerably. It takes longer to compare, and consumes more disk and memory.

We can improve this schema in a couple ways.

If the set of possible action_id's is fixed you could use an [enum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html). These act like text fields, but they're stored as numbers.

```
create type actions as enum (
  'sit', 'stand', 'stop', 'drop', 'roll'
)

create table expanded_flows (
  action_id actions not null
);

insert into expanded_flows (action_id) values ('stop'), ('drop'), ('roll');
```

The upside is it requires no change to your existing queries. The downside is the set is fixed. Every time you want to add a new action you need to alter the schema.

```
alter type actions add value 'scream';
```

Alternatively, make actions their own table with a simple integer ID. Store the text ID in the table.

```
create table actions (
  id bigint generated always as identity,
  name text not null
);

create table expanded_flows (
  action_id bigint not null references actions(id)
);

insert into actions (id, name) values (1, 'scream'), (2, 'shout'), (3, 'doubt');

insert into expanded_flows (action_id) values (3), (1), (2);
```

This is probably the safest and most flexible approach, though it does change how expanded_flows is queried.

---

***Previous answer before I realized action_id was text***.

It's possible Postgres's statistics it uses to plan queries are wrong. Bring them up to date with `vacuum analyze yourtable`.

Postgres might not use the index. If it thinks there's a low cardinality (there's only going to be a few distinct IDs) it will assume scanning the whole table sequentially will be faster than scanning the keys of the index.

You can give it a hint by turning off sequential scans.

```
create table expanded_flows (
  action_id integer not null
);

insert into expanded_flows
select a.*
from generate_series(1,90) a
cross join generate_series(1,900000);

create index action_idx on expanded_flows(action_id);

-- before analyzing it will seq scan taking 35 seconds.
explain analyze SELECT count( distinct action_id ) FROM expanded_flows ;

                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=1370908.00..1370908.01 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=35026.029..35026.030 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on expanded_flows  (cost=0.00..1168408.00 rows=81000000 width=4) (actual time=0.039..7520.377 rows=81000000 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.060 ms
 Execution Time: 35026.059 ms

vacuum analyze expanded_flows;

-- after analyzing with seqscans on, still seq scans taking 35 seconds.
explain analyze SELECT count( distinct action_id ) FROM expanded_flows ;

                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=1370910.60..1370910.61 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=35559.958..35559.959 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on expanded_flows  (cost=0.00..1168410.08 rows=81000208 width=4) (actual time=0.057..7235.677 rows=81000000 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.092 ms
 Execution Time: 35559.996 ms
(4 rows)

set enable_seqscan = off;

-- analyzed, seqscans off, it uses the index taking... about 35 seconds.
explain analyze SELECT count( distinct action_id ) FROM expanded_flows ;

                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                          
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=2307148.21..2307148.22 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=35033.378..35033.379 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using action_idx on expanded_flows  (cost=0.57..2104647.69 rows=81000208 width=4) (actual time=1.315..8392.896 rows=81000000 loops=1)
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.089 ms
 Execution Time: 35033.419 ms
```

The planner was right, the index is no faster than the sequential scan. It takes about 35 seconds which still seems pretty slow for reading 90 keys out of a btree, but it's not 30 minutes. Your millage may vary.

(2018 MacBook Pro, 16 GB, and (critically) an SSD).

Comment: The actual rows returned are 103904895 so the stats are quite accurate